# Elegant way to reduce code duplication between prompting the user to save when closing the program?

Tags: c#, refactoring, code-duplication

When exiting the program if the programmer handles the `FormClosing` event if there is unsaved data the programmer can prompt a save dialog asking them if they want to save, not save, or cancel the operation.

In the FormClosing event if they hit `Cancel`, to cancel the operation you set `e.Cancel = true;`. This is fine. However, in the menu if the user hits the `Exit` button then the same thing should occur except instead of doing `e.Cancel = true;` it should just do `return;` because it's handle menu item `Click` event instead of a `FormClosing` event.

Right now I pretty much have the code duplicated and was wondering if there was a way to handle this to avoid the duplication in an elegant and understandable fashion.

```
private void FrmEditorFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (NeedsToSave)
    {
        DialogResult saveChangesDialog = 
MessageBox.Show("There are unsaved changes. Save now?", 
"Xml Editor", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Save();
        }
        else if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            e.Cancel = true; // Only difference
        }
    }
}

private void ExitToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NeedsToSave)
    {
        DialogResult saveChangesDialog = 
MessageBox.Show("There are unsaved changes. Save now?", 
"Xml Editor", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Save();
        }
        else if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return; // Only difference
        }
    }

    Close();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. Calling Close in your menu click handler should cause the FormClosing event to fire and you can cancel it there.

Comment: @MattBurland: Oh wow I didn't even realize. If you answer with that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this. Calling Close in your menu click handler should cause the FormClosing event to fire and you can cancel it there.

Answer (score 1):

Place the common code in a method that returns a *bool* to indicate whether a save happened or not

```
private bool PromptSave()
{
    if (NeedsToSave)
    {
        DialogResult saveChangesDialog = 
            MessageBox.Show("There are unsaved changes. Save now?", "Xml Editor",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Save();
            return true;
        }
        else if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use that return value to set *e.Cancel*

Answer (score 0):

Separate it into a different function that return a boolean value. Something like this:

```
bool ConfirmSave()
{
    if (NeedsToSave)
    {
        DialogResult saveChangesDialog = MessageBox.Show("There are unsaved changes. Save now?", "Xml Editor",
                                                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Save();
            return true;
        }
        else if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

This function can be called from anywhere a close event happens, and you can handle the results accordingly.

```
private void FrmEditorFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(!ConfirmSave())
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }   
}

private void ExitToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConfirmSave();

    Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty close

```
private void ExitToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (DoSaveOnExit())
    Save();
  else
    return;
}  

private void FrmEditorFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if (DoSaveOnExit())
    Save();
   else
    e.Cancel = true;             
}
private bool DoSaveOnExit()
{
  if (NeedsToSave)
  {
     DialogResult saveChangesDialog = MessageBox.Show("T", "Xml Editor",
     MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (saveChangesDialog == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Or what Matt Burland wrote.  :)